# Minimize Energy Function

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be symmetric positive definite matrix and $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. How to prove that $A\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{b}$ if and only if $\mathbf{u}$ minimizes the so-called energy function $$F(\mathbf{v})=\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{v}^\mathsf{T}A\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{b}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{v}.$$

What I try: assume $A\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{b}$ then

$$F(\mathbf{v})-F(\mathbf{u})=\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{v}^\mathsf{T}A\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{b}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{v}-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{u}^\mathsf{T}A\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{b}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{u}.$$
I can't show that above expression is non negative, i.e. $F(\mathbf{v})-F(\mathbf{u})\ge0$ for any $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to observe when $Au = b $, using symmetry and Au = b
$$\frac{1}{2} (u-v)^TA(u-v) = \frac{1}{2}v^tAv - b^Tv + \frac{1}{2} u^TAu $$
Here are details for the above equation:
$$ = \frac{1}{2}(u^TAu - u^TAv - v^TAu + v^TAv) $$
Using Au = b here
$$ = \frac{1}{2}(u^TAu - (A^Tu)^v - v^Tb + v^TAv )$$
Using $A^Tu = Au = b$ here
$$ = \frac{1}{2}(u^TAu - b^Tv - b^Tv - v^TAv)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}v^TAv - b^Tv + \frac{1}{2}u^TAu$$
And $$ \frac{1}{2} u^TAu = -\frac{1}{2}u^TAu +u^TAu = -\frac{1}{2}u^TAu + b^Tu$$
so we have for all v,
$$\frac{1}{2} (u-v)^TA(u-v) = \frac{1}{2}v^tAv - b^Tv - (\frac{1}{2}u^tAu - b^Tu) = F(v) - F(u) \ge 0$$

Taking derivatice in other direction is OK.

Comment: Can you elaborate your first equation?

Comment: Her is the details added

Answer (score 0):

The function $f$ is convex (since $A \ge 0$) and smooth, hence $u$ is a 
global minimum **iff** $f'(u) = 0$.

In this case, $f'(u) = (Au-b)^T$.